# BootBox - Unexpected identifier error

Tags: jquery, bootbox

Im wondering if someone could help me out with a bit of code.

Im using BootBox for some Modal windows, i want to add some custom HTML to the confirm method, but i dont think im doing it right.

My code is below:

```
    $('.next').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       bootbox.confirm({

            message: "I am a testing message",
            title: "Please confirm you have enrolled"

            callback: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    location.href = href;
                }               
            }

       });
    });
```

The error im getting is as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: on which line you are getting this error??..and i think you have a typo ... there is a missing `,` after `title: "Please confirm you have enrolled"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

**Your original code**

```
title: "Please confirm you have enrolled"
callback: function (result) {
   if (result) {
      location.href = href;
   }               
}
```

**New code**

```
title: "Please confirm you have enrolled",
callback: function (result) {
   if (result) {
      location.href = href;
   }               
}
```

Note the "," character at the end of the `title` line.

Comment: Oh i cant believe i missed that ... Thank you